# Why can't the second class get variable data from third class?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am having a problem with passing of variables between classes.

The problem that I am having is that the second class is not obtaining the variable data from the third class after first class sets the value to teh variables in third class.

The way in which I would like it to work is that I have one class (classA) where it obtains the value from the user and calls the set method is the third class to set the value to the variable, second class (classB) will be used get the value using the get method in the third class and the third class (ClassC) is where get and set methods resides.

ClassA method coding:

```
//method for 'add' button functionality
    public void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        ArrayList<UserInfo> userobjList = new ArrayList<>();
        //calling data field revelant text fields
        int EmpNumber = Integer.parseInt(txtEmpNum.getText());
        String EmpAccessType = txtAccessType.getText();
        //creating the object to parse data to userinfo class
        UserInfo user = new UserInfo(EmpNumber, EmpAccessType);
        //setting the data to varibales in userinfo class
        user.setEmpNumber(EmpNumber);
        user.setEmpAccessType(EmpAccessType);
        //adds the object to the arraylist
        userobjList.add(user);
        //creates the object to use the method for adding employee to system
        AddEmpFunction addUser = new AddEmpFunction();        
        addUser.test();
    }
```

This class obtains user information and sets the data in the third class

ClassB method for adding user to system coding:

```
//variables
    int EmpNumber;
    String AccessTypes;
    //creation of object to be used throughout
    UserInfo user = new UserInfo(EmpNumber, AccessTypes);    
public void AddNewEmpLogin()
        {
            try
            {
                //SQL string command to be executed to add user login details
                String addNewUserLogin = "insert into userLoginData(Username, accessType) values (" 
                        + user.getEmpNum() + ","
                        + quotate(user.getEmpAccessType()) + ")";
                //create the statement that will be used
                Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
                //executes the addNewUser statement
                stmt.executeUpdate(addNewUserLogin); 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //exception error message is shown
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error adding new User's details \n " + e, "Database Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
```

This class is where the data will be obtained from third class and then stored in MySQL.

ClassC is where the get and set methods are:

```
private int EmpNumber;
private String EmpAccessType;
//constructor
    public UserInfo(int EmpNumber, String EmpAccessType)
    {
        this.EmpNumber = EmpNumber;
        this.EmpAccessType = EmpAccessType;
    }
public int getEmpNum()
    {
        return EmpNumber;
    }
    public void setEmpNum(int EmpNum)
    {
        this.EmpNumber = EmpNum;
    }
public String getEmpAccessType()
    {
        return EmpAccessType;
    }
    public void setEmpAccessType(String EmpAccessType)
    {
        this.EmpAccessType = EmpAccessType;
    }
```

The data is passing perfectly well from classA to classC but the data returned in classB whcih calls it up form classC displays null for the string and 0 for the integer.

Please could someone please explain where my problem is and how I can fix this. I have read a lot about get and set methods and there is no actualy example for what I am trying to achieve.

Any help will be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have two different *instances* of the third class.  You're doing this in one place (variable names changed to illustrate):

```
UserInfo userA = new UserInfo();
userA.setEmpNumber(EmpNumber);
userA.setEmpAccessType(EmpAccessType);
```

And then this in another:

```
UserInfo userB = new UserInfo();
userB.getEmpNumber();
userB.getEmpAccessType();
```

So you set data on one object, and then try to get that data from another object.  But you can't, because no data was ever set on that object.

As an analogy, consider two identical cars.  Same make, same model, came off the same production line.  You are putting gas into one car, then trying to drive the other one.  But you can't.  Because it doesn't have any gas in it.

You need to use the *same* instance of the object:

```
UserInfo user = new UserInfo();
user.setEmpNumber(EmpNumber);
user.setEmpAccessType(EmpAccessType);
// ...
user.getEmpNumber();
user.getEmpAccessType();
```

If your second class needs a valid instance of your third class in order to perform its task, then it should require that as a constructor parameter.  So when the first class holds that `user` variable and then creates an instance of the second class, it passes the `user` variable to that instance.  So there's only *one* `user`.

(Additionally, as a side note, you don't need to pass the values to the constructor *and* use the setters.  One or the other is fine.  A value only needs to be set once.)

Comment: thanks you for your help. I see where my problem is. I will sort it out. Thanks for pointing the problem out to me. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

`int EmpNumber;
    String AccessTypes;
    //creation of object to be used throughout
    UserInfo user = new UserInfo(EmpNumber, AccessTypes);`

You set up new user with no field filled.

And then you

`+ user.getEmpNum() + ","
+ quotate(user.getEmpAccessType()) + ")";`

from your empty `user` so it returns `0` and `null` respectively.
Pass your `user` from classA to classB first?

Answer (score 0):

Your class B does not seem to receive data from class A. 
Class C, `UserInfo` is a data store object (POJO) but the instance `user` that is created in class A is never passed to class B in your sample code.

As a matter of fact, class B seems to create its own instance of `UserInfo` with empty values.

So, to keep this short: pass the `user` object from class A to B, for example by using `AddEmpLogin( UserInfo user )`.

Next, read a solid introduction to object-oriented programming.